# How to resolve error 415 Unsupported Media Type when Content-Type is correctly set

Tags: karate

I have a simple POST request that requires a json Content-Type header and a body like

```
{
   oneNbr: "2016004444",
   twoCode: "@@@",
   threeNbr: "STD PACK",
   sheetTitle: "010000",
   codeType: "AF14"
}
```

When I run this in Postman, it runs as expected, returning 200 status and the expected response.

Here's the same script in Karate:

```
  Scenario: Sample test
    * def payload =
      """
    {
       oneNbr: "2016004444",
       twoCode: "@@@",
       threeNbr: "STD PACK",
       sheetTitle: "010000",
       codeType: "AF14"
    }
      """
    Given path '/my_end_point/endpoint'
    And request payload
    When method post
    Then status 200
```

When I run this, it returns {"code":"415","status":"Unsupported Media Type"}. The  console output shows that the right content-type is being set during the POST.

Even if I specifically set the content-type in the script, 415 is still returned e.g.

```
And header Content-Type = 'application/json'
```

OR

```
* configure headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell what content-type your server is receiving? I'd suggest looking in the Postman console for the full request/headers Postman is making and comparing that to the request logged in the Karate console. From what you've described it could be that your server is blowing up on something else.

Comment: @Alex J Thanks for the suggestion. Did this and did not lead anywhere new. Also tried another rest tool, Advanced Rest Client, to compare. The API call worked fine there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did some debugging and found that Karate automatically appends 'charset=UTF-8' to the Content-Type header. The API does not expect charset.

Found the following post and that solved the problem:

[How can I send just 'application/json' as the content-type header with Karate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53472047/how-can-i-send-just-application-json-as-the-content-type-header-with-karate/53474225#53474225)

Posting this to help others in future.

Comment: BTW most likely your API is not standards compliant.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Try to use this in your background.

```
* def charset = null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `* header Accept = 'application/json'` header. The one difference between Karate and Postman is that Postman tries to be smart and auto-adds an `Accept` header - whereas Karate does not.

Comment: I had tried that also. Just tried it again. It does not resolve the issue. Is there any way debug such issues further?