# How can I send just 'application/json' as the content-type header with Karate?

Tags: karate

I'm trying to write my first test for a service that I have no control over. The service validates headers on incoming requests and for the content-type header it requires that the value be `application/json`, and only that value. However when I try to write a test and explicitly set the content-type header to only have this value, the header that is generated has the following value instead: `application/json; charset=UTF-8`

This additional `charset=UTF-8` value is preventing my test from passing. Is there anyway to prevent Karate from adding it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default setting of `UTF-8` on `Content-Type` can be overide by this,

`* configure charset = null`

Please refer `charset` in `configure` table from [karate documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure)