# karate test - disable encoding utf-8

Tags: karate

Karate test - encoding issue.
My subsystem is not expecting any encoding in the header, but when I am trying to test that service, by default the header -  Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 is going.

Is there any way to disable this encoding in karate test

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/53472047/8615449 please refer this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53474225/8615449.

Comment: great. please delete this question and refer the commented one

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the same issue. Configure charset to be null
`* configure charset = null`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53651454/6518053