# Post XML Karate API

Tags: karate

I'm trying to post XML using karate API. When I run the test case as junit test, I'm getting the following error:

> **ERROR com.intuit.karate - status code was: 415, expected: 200,** "message":"Content type 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported"
>
> The XML input enclosed within """  """ is provided as a part of the
>   feature file: Example:
>   * text test =
>
> """
>
> """

My feature file contains the following:

```
Given header Content-Type = 'application/xml; charset=UTF-8'
And header Accept = 'application/json; text/plain;*/*'
```

Can someone help me solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this sounds like a case where the server has trouble with the UTF-8 part

Try only this:

```
* def xml =
"""
<some>xml</some>
"""
* configure charset = null
* request xml
```

Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53564204/143475

Comment: also from his example i see * text test =, this is supposed to be * xml test = """ xml """ right?

Comment: @peter The xml that needs to be posted is a string of arrays. Will the same format be applicable even in case of string of arrays?

Comment: @ashwin I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @peter I'm getting the following error when I run my test:
[Fatal Error] :57:3: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".
14:15:52.927 [main] WARN  com.intuit.karate - xml parsing failed, response data type set to string: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 57; columnNumber: 3; The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".
[Fatal Error] :2:6: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

Comment: @ashwin the time has come for me to point you to this page. all the best: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue